# Dynamic rendering of controls - What to use Custom ASP.NET MVC HTML Helper or Partial View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have all the controls (such as TextBox, Dropdown) saved in the Database which I have to render on the screen dynamically using some kind of loop. So, please suggest me the pros and cons of using Custom ASP.NET MVC 4 HTML Helper or Partial View. My DB Data model would be something like below.

### Control Table

ControlID, ControlType, Value, LabelText.

Note: I can't change the architecture of having control data in the Database. So, please refrain from suggesting that :).

Thanks in Adavance!!

Comment: The inbuilt html helpers wont help you with this.

Comment: Correct, I was talking about custom HTML Helper :)

Comment: Give a try to knockOut.js, that way it provides feature to add/remove the controls dynamically and the values of the controls directly get reflected in the json model. Once done just post the JSON to controller to save or update. Knockout is good candidate for dynamic contents as its two way binding.